# nltk lookup error in Stanford Neural Dependency Parser

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I am trying to use the Stanford Neural Dependency Parser provided by nltk. The problem I'm having is that when I call `st = nltk.parse.stanford.StanfordNeuralDependencyParser()`, I get the following error:

```
>>> st = nltk.parse.stanford.StanfordNeuralDependencyParser()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-5-ca2dec4f3c1f>", line 1, in <module>
    st = nltk.parse.stanford.StanfordNeuralDependencyParser()
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\stanford.py", line 378, in __init__
    super(StanfordNeuralDependencyParser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\stanford.py", line 51, in __init__
    key=lambda model_name: re.match(self._JAR, model_name)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 714, in find_jar_iter
    raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))
LookupError: 

===========================================================================
  NLTK was unable to find stanford-corenlp-(\d+)(\.(\d+))+\.jar! Set
  the CLASSPATH environment variable.

  For more information, on stanford-corenlp-(\d+)(\.(\d+))+\.jar, see:
    <http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml>
===========================================================================
```

But, when I run `os.environ.get('CLASSPATH')` I get the result

```
`C:\nltk_data\;C:\nltk_data\stanford\;C:\nltk_data\stanford\stanford-ner\`
```

I know that I have the `corenlp` jar file in `C:\nltk_data\stanford\` so I run the following and end up with a slightly different error.

```
>>> st = nltk.parse.stanford.StanfordNeuralDependencyParser('C:\\nltk_data\\stanford\\')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2885, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-22-28d797d702d9>", line 1, in <module>
    st = StanfordNeuralDependencyParser('C:\\nltk_data\\stanford\\')
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\stanford.py", line 378, in __init__
    super(StanfordNeuralDependencyParser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\stanford.py", line 51, in __init__
    key=lambda model_name: re.match(self._JAR, model_name)
  File "C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 635, in find_jar_iter
    (name_pattern, path_to_jar))
LookupError: Could not find stanford-corenlp-(\d+)(\.(\d+))+\.jar jar file at C:\nltk_data\stanford\
```

I have downloaded the jar *stanford-english-corenlp-2016-01-10-models.jar* from the Stanford NLP website and also renamed it to *stanford-corenlp-2016-01-10.jar* to try and match the pattern but I was still end up with the same errors. I have also downloaded the Stanford Parser version 3.6.0 but it doesn't contain any corenlp files.

Is there any way to get this to work, or am I misunderstanding something?